# How to send HTML-Mail with a "preview-icon"

Tags: html, responsive-design, phpmailer, html-email

I would like to send HTML-formatted mails with an icon that is shown in the preview list on mobile devices. 
I've uploaded a screenshot to show what I mean. For example mails from twitter are displayed with the "little bird", mails from my bank "1822 direkt" are also displayed with the specific brand-logo. How it's possible to include "preview-logos"?

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you tried...add some code, show examples and explain the problem. This is not a code request forum.

Comment: View source on the message - there may be some special message header or HTML meta tag that defines it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard for displaying icons, i suspect the app you are using to read them is looking up the favicon of the email domain.